# JavaFX : Adding a new node to Scene in java code when Scene is initially loaded from FXML

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

How can I add a new node to the Scene in java code when Scene is initially loaded from FXML ?
I have loaded from FXML as shown below

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));

Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 600, Color.DODGERBLUE);
```

Now say for example how do I add button to the scene in Java code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I do not know the reason behind your question. If what you want is to insert some nodes dynamically during the application or scene initialization, I suggest you use a [`initialize` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#fxml_annotation) at your controller.

This method must be annotated with `@FXML` and have the following signature:

```
void initialize()
```

Then, you can inject the container where the button must be inserted on the controller and add the button to it:

```
@FXML
HBox buttonBox // assuming your button container is a HBox
...

@FXML
protected void initialize() {
    buttonBox.getChildren().add(new Button("Click me!"));
}
```

The method `initialize` is called after the components defined at the FXML file were built.

Answer (score 8):

Here is one way to do this:

```
((VBox) root).getChildren().add(new Button("Java Button"));
```

The snippet above assumes that the top container defined in your FXML is a VBox, if it is not a VBox, just cast it to whatever type you have chosen.

> I wonder how I can determine the type of the container at runtime, so I can write a more generic code.

The type is likely a [Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html), so casting to a Pane will work in most cases.  Using a layout Pane as a Parent is usually recommended for most layout tasks in JavaFX.

Comment: This approach is simpler and worked fine for me. I wonder how I can determine the type of the container at runtime, so I can write a more generic code.

Comment: root instanceof xxx or use getClass() should work for testing or use reflection to find wanted method?