# How to add a group to the scene in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, fxml

FXML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.net.URL?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="apMain" prefHeight="600" prefWidth="600" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="funkcje.FXMLDocumentController">
     <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@style.css" />
    </stylesheets>
    <children>
        <Button prefHeight="20" prefWidth="70" layoutX="265" layoutY="550" text="Narysuj" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
        <Label layoutX="30" layoutY="500" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" text="Podaj A:" fx:id="labelA" />
        <TextField layoutX="105" layoutY="503" prefHeight="20" prefWidth="90" fx:id="textfieldA" />
        <Label layoutX="200" layoutY="500" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" text="Podaj B:" fx:id="labelB" />
        <TextField layoutX="275" layoutY="503" prefHeight="20" prefWidth="90" fx:id="textfieldB" />
        <Label layoutX="370" layoutY="500" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" text="Podaj miare:" fx:id="labelC" />
        <TextField layoutX="483" layoutY="503" prefHeight="20" prefWidth="90" fx:id="textfieldC" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

FXML controller:

```
    package funkcje;

    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.scene.Group;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

    /**
     *
     * 
     */
    public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

        @FXML
        private Label label;
        private AnchorPane apMain;

        @FXML
        private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("You clicked me!");
            label.setText("Hello World!");
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
            // TODO
            Group group = new Group();
            Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(250, 25, 100, 140);
            r2.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            r2.setFill(null);
            r2.setStrokeWidth(3);
            r2.setArcWidth(25);
            r2.setArcHeight(25);
            group.getChildren().add(r2);

            apMain.getChildren().add(group);

        }    

    }

main app:

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package funkcje;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 *
 */
public class Funkcje extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setTitle("Funkcje");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Here it is. Help me.
There's some text, I cant post it, because I have too much code and less text.
Here it is. Help me.
There's some text, I cant post it, because I have too much code and less text.
Here it is. Help me.
There's some text, I cant post it, because I have too much code and less text.
Here it is. Help me.
There's some text, I cant post it, because I have too much code and less text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152639/javafx-adding-a-new-node-to-scene-in-java-code-when-scene-is-initially-loaded

Comment: A scene only has one node: the root. If you want to add more nodes, you would add them to the root. (You need the root to be a `Pane` or a `Group` in order to call `getChildren().add(canva)`.)

Comment: I did the solution from link above, but rectangle doesnt show. look at the code in post

Comment: You didn't do anything with the group you created

Comment: so what should I do with it?

Comment: so what should I do with it?

Comment: Add it to some pane that is displayed in the scene...

Comment: It seems his problem is that he is creating the group in the app Main. He should only be creating it in the Controller.

Comment: You have to chose to write a program that is totally written in the app's Main or you have to use the FXML file and it's controller the correct way. You are trying to mix the two approaches.

Comment: Post your fxml file.

Comment: I did nothing in fxml file.
In controller I've got second code.
In main app I have got third code.

Comment: Read my comments from above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your FXMLDocumentController.java file change:

```
private AnchorPane apMain;
```

To:

```
@FXML private AnchorPane apMain;
```

Comment: Finally I've got my rectangle drawn! thank you, sorry for asking for simple things, but I'm new to javafx