# Add JavaFX Label - (Using Only Java / JavaFX Code) - To Existing GUI Created With Scenebuilder / FXML

Tags: javafx, label, fxml, scenebuilder

1. I Created a complete GUI using ONLY Scenebuilder FXML Techniques

Something Like This :-

```
    public class Main extends Application {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       launch(args);
   }

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
       Parent root=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("backupmenu.fxml"));            

       primaryStage.setTitle("Backup Affected Files And Folders Only");
       primaryStage.setScene(new Scene( root,   800, 400));

       primaryStage.show();
   }


}
```

However I want to add a label to that SAME EXISTING GUI but this time using ONLY Java Code / JavaFX Label Techniques ?

I.E Using Traditional Methods such as this Example Below :-

```
  // launch the application
   public void start(Stage s)
   {
       // set title for the stage
       s.setTitle("creating label");

       // create a label
       Label b = new Label("This is a label");

       // create a Stack pane
       StackPane rootpane = new StackPane();

       // add password field
       rootpane.getChildren().add(b);

       // create a scene
       Scene sc = new Scene(rootpane, 200, 200);

       // set the scene
       s.setScene(sc);

       s.show();
   }

   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       // launch the application
       launch(args);
   }
}
```

I cannot find a web search result that even comes close to matching my very specific question .
Can i combine the 2 techniques - Is it Possible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX : Adding a new node to Scene in java code when Scene is initially loaded from FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152639/javafx-adding-a-new-node-to-scene-in-java-code-when-scene-is-initially-loaded)

Comment: An FXML file can be "translated" to java instructions to create a scene. Everything you can do from an fxml can be done in java code too. It's hard to see how exactly you want to modify the scene, but usually with fxml it's done from the controller.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible.

You need a reference to the `Parent` (some kind of container `Pane` or `Node`) you want to add the `Label` to in your controller class.

For example, suppose your FXML defines a `VBox` with an id of "root":

```
<VBox fx:id="root">
```

In your controller, define a reference to that `VBox`:

```
@FXML
private VBox root;
```

Then you can add anything you want to the `VBox`:

```
root.getChildren().add(new Label("Hi, I'm a new Label!"));
```

Comment: Thank You Zephyr - this worked nicely and is a great answer , there is another possible way suggested by Slaw above i need to explore , before making a final  choice, really appreciate your input to myself (and others) issues